# Pandas drop_duplicates. Keep first AND last. Is it possible?

Tags: pandas, drop-duplicates

I have this dataframe and I need to drop all duplicates but I need to keep first AND last values

For example:

```
1      0

2     0

3     0

4     0
```

output:

```
1     0

4     0
```

I tried `df.column.drop_duplicates(keep=("first","last"))` but it doesn't word, it returns

> ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False

Does anyone know any turn around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [panda's concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) function to create a dataframe with both the first and last values.

```
pd.concat([
    df['X'].drop_duplicates(keep='first'),
    df['X'].drop_duplicates(keep='last'),
])
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't drop both first and last... so trick is too concat data frames of first and last.

When you concat one has to handle creating duplicate of non-duplicates.  So only concat unique indexes in 2nd Dataframe.   (not sure if Merge/Join would work better?)

```
import pandas as pd

d = {1:0,2:0,10:1, 3:0,4:0}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['cnt'])
print(df)

    cnt
1     0
2     0
10    1
3     0
4     0
```

Then do this:

```
d1 = df.drop_duplicates(keep=("first"))
d2 = df.drop_duplicates(keep=("last"))
d3 = pd.concat([d1,d2.loc[set(d2.index) - set(d1.index)]])
d3
Out[60]:
cnt
1   0
10  1
4   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a groupby on your column named `column`, then reindex. If you ever want to check for duplicate values in more than one column, you can extend the columns you include in your groupby.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[0,0,0,0]})
```

---

Input:

```
   column
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       0
```

---

```
df.groupby('column', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.iloc[[0, -1]]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   column
0       0
3       0
```