# How to remove rows with multiple occurrences in a row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have this data:

```
     A  
1    1 
2    1 
3    1  
4    2
5    2
6    1
```

i expect to get:

```
     A  
1    1 
-    -   -> (drop)
3    1  
4    2
5    2
6    1
```

I want to drop all the rows in col ['A'] with the same value that appear in a row,
but without the first and the last ones.

Until now I used:

`df = df.loc[df[col].shift() != df[col]]`

but it will remove also the last appearance.

Sorry for my bad English, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to group consecutive numbers, which can be achieved by `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
print (df.groupby(df["A"].diff().ne(0).cumsum(), as_index=False).nth([0, -1]))

   A
1  1
3  1
4  2
5  2
6  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the same problem as this question: [Pandas drop_duplicates. Keep first AND last. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721639/pandas-drop-duplicates-keep-first-and-last-is-it-possible).

The suggested solution is:

```
pd.concat([
    df['A'].drop_duplicates(keep='first'),
    df['A'].drop_duplicates(keep='last'),
])
```

Update after clarification:

First get the boolean masks for your described criteria:

```
is_last = df['A'] != df['A'].shift(-1)
is_duplicate = df['A'] == df['A'].shift()
```

And drop the rows based on these:

```
df.drop(df.index[~is_last & is_duplicate]) # note the ~ to negate is_last
```

Comment: drop_duplicates will drop all the rows with the same value in all of the table, I need to drop only if the value appearance in a row.

Comment: if I run the code output will be:
     A
[1 ,  1]
[4 ,  2]
[5 ,  2]
[6 ,  1]